# How to Prevent SVN automerge for WebSite Development

Tags: svn, iis, web, jenkins, merge

Currently we use SVN where we have branches likes this

```
Development 
 -Site1
 -Site2
 -Site3
Production
 -Site1
 -Site2
 -Site3
Sandbox
-Site1
 -Site2
 -Site3
```

All the webpage development is done from the Development branch and on commits the dev website is updated.   When we are ready to go live with a feature we merge that into the production branch (which was originally branched from development).

When we merge to the next branch we will never want to actually merge files but just replace or add them so i have the team disable the tortiase automerge capabilities.

I have two questions:

1. is there a better method for using SVN for managing websites.
2. Sometimes I manaually update my dev and staging servers configs but then Jenkins will do an update and do its own silent merge, is there a way to disable Jenkins from doing this, does Jenkins use the same SVN as whats installed on the system?